# Loading font from URL to Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to load a font with Pillow library directly from url, preferably into Google Colab? I tried something like

`from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont`    `ImageFont.truetype("https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/master/src/hinted/Roboto-Regular.ttf?raw=true", 15)`

Yet I get an error of *OSError: cannot open resource*. I tried with Google Fonts too, but to no avail.
[image]

Comment: How about making it easier for folk to assist you by providing a useable URL?

Comment: My bad, Mark; updated the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO

req = requests.get("https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/master/src/hinted/Roboto-Regular.ttf?raw=true")

font = ImageFont.truetype(BytesIO(req.content), 72)
```

Comment: That's a quick one. Worth mentioning that BytesIO lives in io library, we'd need to import that one too. What if the font is in a zip file, do you have a quick hint for that? Or is it better to post another question?

Comment: Questions are free (and answers) so go ahead and ask another... being careful to provide a representative URL 

Comment: Added another question here, maybe you can take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730209/accessing-extracted-zip-file-in-colab

Answer (score 4):

You can 
(1) Fetch the font with HTTP GET request, using [urllib.request.urlopen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)
(2) memoize the result with [@functools.lrucache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) or [@memoization.cache](https://github.com/lonelyenvoy/python-memoization) so the font is not fetched every time you run the function and 
(3) Pass the contents as a file-like object with [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)

```py
from PIL import ImageFont
import urllib.request
import functools
import io


@functools.lru_cache
def get_font_from_url(font_url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(font_url).read()


def webfont(font_url):
    return io.BytesIO(get_font_from_url(font_url))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    font_url = "https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/master/src/hinted/Roboto-Regular.ttf?raw=true"
    with webfont(font_url) as f:
        imgfnt = ImageFont.truetype(f, 15)
```

There is also [python-memoization](https://github.com/lonelyenvoy/python-memoization) (`pip install memoization`) for alternative way of memoizing. Usage would be

```
from memoization import cache 

@cache
def get_font_from_url(font_url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(font_url).read()
```

#### memoization speed

Without memoization:

```
In [1]: timeit get_font_from_url(font_url)
The slowest run took 4.95 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1.32 s ± 1.11 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With memoization:

````
In [1]: timeit get_font_from_url(font_url)
The slowest run took 11.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
271 ns ± 341 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```t
````

Comment: That's good and thorough, thank you for this. @Mark 's response is still a quick short solution, so I'll accept his answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah I would actually not written an answer if I had seen there is already one. You could add to this some retrying (for example using tenacity) and also zip-file handling. Zip-file handling could be done just by adding a parameter: `webfont(font_url, filetype='zip')` and then adding unzip if asked for.