# Get a list of all available fonts in PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to find out what fonts are available to be used in PIL with the `font = ImageFont.load()` and/or `ImageFont.truetype()` function. I want to create a list from which I can sample a random font to be used. I haven't found anything in the documentation so far, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use any font file you have on your computer and can load millions more from anywhere on the Internet https://stackoverflow.com/a/64716673/2836621 so there's no real answer to this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have so far not found a solution with `PIL` but `matplotlib` has a function to get all the available fonts from the system:

`system_fonts = matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')`

The font can then be loaded using `fnt = ImageFont.truetype(font, 60)`

Comment: This didn't work for me, but `from matplotlib import font_manager font_manager.get_font_names()` did, perhaps an update to  3.6.0