# Plotting an Image from GitHub using pyscript and matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, python-imaging-library, pyscript, pyodide

Using pyscript it's easy to load in raw data from GitHub, like in the intro tutorial where you read in a Pandas DataFrame like so:

```py
url = (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cheukting/pyscript-ice-cream/main/bj-products.csv"
)
ice_data = pd.read_csv(open_url(url))
```

I would like to do something similar, but load in a jpg file and plot it using matplotlib. Would someone be able to help me understand what I should be doing here? I am very new to using pyscript.

I would think that the code required to do that would look something like the below, but I haven't been able to get anything working.

```py
from pyodide.http import open_url
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))

image = Image.open(open_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/img.jpg"))
ax.imshow(image)
display(fig, target="graph-area", append=False)
```

Comment: Use `requests.get()` and `BytesIO` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64716673/2836621 but pass the `BytesIO` to `Image.open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks TachyonicBytes, I was able to get that work in the most recent pyscript version by doing the following

```py
import asyncio
from pyodide.http import pyfetch
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

async def plot_image(url):
    img = await pyfetch(url)
    res = await img.bytes()
    iobuf = io.BytesIO(res)
    image = Image.open(iobuf)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
    ax.imshow(image)

    display(fig, target="graph-area", append=False)

asyncio.ensure_future(plot_image(url))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, as Mark proposed

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

req = requests.get(
    "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/doc/images/meanshift_basics.jpg?raw=true"
)

image = Image.open(BytesIO(req.content))

plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, based on what searching I've done I don't think that you can use the `requests` library within `pyscript` though. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I have never used pyscript before, sorry

Comment: @JustinEssert You're correct, the stdlib library `requests` doesn't work in PyScript/Pyodide. However, the `pyodide-http` library patches some of the main functions of `requests` to allow for some interoperability - see, for instance, this example from the PyScript docs: https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/requests.html

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work in the online version of [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/console.html):

```py
from pyodide.http import open_url
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import io

img = await pyodide.http.pyfetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyodide/pyodide/main/docs/_static/img/pyodide-logo-readme.png")
res = await img.bytes()
iobuf = io.BytesIO(res)
image = Image.open(iobuf)

ax.imshow(image)
display(fig, target="graph-area", append=False)
```

The idea was that you have to get files ([`pyfetch`](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api/http.html#pyodide.http.pyfetch) was recommended by the pyodide documentation), then you have to wait for all the coroutines and wrap the bytes into an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), in order to be read like a file.

Edit: The last part of the code is taken from your example, but won't work, because `display` seems not to be bound to anything. `ax.imshow` should plot the image in a gui environment of pyodide.